# How can I clear the screen in openGL using Java

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I don't understand how I can simply clear the screen in Java while using OpenGL. I have searched all over the internet, there is like no real good resource for OpenGL information. Basically I just want to clear the screen and re-draw a circle. Instead my code decides that it isn't going to clear the screen ever, and it most definitely isn't going to draw anything else.. I want it to clear the screen when I press "e", and then draw a new circle. I have two java files.. I will only post relevant code for the sake of any user's who can help me - but will post more code if needed.

In the beginning of my **JOGLEventListener.java** file I'm also declaring a global var

// Test
GLAutoDrawable test = null;

**JOGLEventListener.java**

```
    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) 
    {
        // Set a global variable to hold the gLDrawable
        // May not need this?
        test = gLDrawable;

         GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

        gl.glClearColor(backrgb[0], 0, 1, 1);
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        backrgb[0]+=0.0005;
        if (backrgb[0]> 1) backrgb[0] = 0; 


        // =============================================
        // Draw my circle here
        //
        // =============================================
        // =============================================
        System.out.println("Drawing Circle..");
        drawCircle(5.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f);

    }

    // Draw Circle
    void drawCircle(float x, float y, float radius)
    {
        System.out.println("IN DRAWCIRCLE");
        int i;
        GL2 gl = test.getGL().getGL2();
        int lineAmount = 100; //# of triangles used to draw circle
        final 
        //GLfloat radius = 0.8f; //radius
        float twicePi = (float) (2.0f * Math.PI);

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINE_LOOP);
            for(i = 0; i <= lineAmount;i++) { 
                gl.glVertex2f(
                    x + (radius * (float)Math.cos(i *  twicePi / lineAmount)), 
                    y + (radius* (float)Math.sin(i * twicePi / lineAmount))
                );
            }
        gl.glEnd();
    }

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
{
    char key= e.getKeyChar();
    System.out.printf("Key typed: %c\n", key); 
    GL2 gl = test.getGL().getGL2();
    if(key == 'e')
    {
        // WHY ISNT THIS WORKING
        // CLEAR THE SCREEN AND DRAW ME A NEW CIRCLE
        gl.glClear( gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );     
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    
        //test
        float x = 100.0f;
        float y = 100.0f;
        float twicePi = (float) (2.0f * Math.PI);
        float radius = 100f;

        System.out.println("Draw Another Circle...");
        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINE_LOOP);
        for(int i = 0; i <= 360;i++) 
        { 
            gl.glVertex2f(
                x + (radius * (float)Math.cos(i *  twicePi / 360)), 
                y + (radius* (float)Math.sin(i * twicePi / 360))
            );
        }
        gl.glEnd();
    }
```

Comment: 'twicePi' is called [tau](http://tauday.com/).

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE, not just a small piece of code: http://sscce.org Put all code responsible for OpenGL drawing in GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable), your key listener shouldn't make OpenGL calls without being sure that your OpenGL is current on this thread. Rather modify some variables in your key listener and take their changes into account in GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) That's [deprecated OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL), don't use it

2) Don't save the `gl` object to one global value, always get it from the `drawable` or the `GLContext`

3) Use a shader program to render and a vertex buffer to hold the vertices position. But first, I'd suggest you to start a tutorial to learn the basic of OpenGL. Or if you want to get something working asap, clone this [hello triangle](https://github.com/elect86/helloTriangle) of mine and start experiment on that

Comment: Your very last link is broken. I agree with your comment, especially your second remark.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is apparently that you don't swap the front and back buffers.

I'm not familiar with the OpenGL bindings for Java, but I guess that the library already does that for you after it calls the `display()` function. It doesn't do that after `keyTyped()`.

The way you are supposed to do this is to always draw the scene *from scratch* inside the `display()` function based on some internal state. Then in `keyTyped()` you shall modify that internal state and invalidate the window, which will cause the `display()` to be called again and redraw the scene properly.

**EDIT:** Calling `display()` yourself won't be enough. I can't find how to invalidate the window in Java (in C this would be so much easier). As a dirty hack you can try calling `temp.swapBuffers()` manually in `display`, setting `setAutoSwapBufferMode(false)` and calling `display` from `keyTyped()`.

Comment: Are you implying that I should call the display() function again in my keyPressed event ?

Comment: I'm just really confused on how to implement what you're saying which isn't really a solution. Like it makes sense, but I don't know what or how to do that.. The problem is there is no information online aside from the "resetting" and "clearing" code I'm already using

Comment: Your suggestion is overcomplicated, Shammy should just perform OpenGL calls in the correct callbacks in which the OpenGL context is current on the right thread. There is no need to call display(), this is the job of the Animator. There is no need to swap the buffers by yourself as it's done automatically.

Comment: @gouessej: how do you cause an Animator to redraw only when things are invalidated rather than at a constant FPS? (i.e. the OP needs an analogue of `glutPostRedisplay`.)

Comment: @ybungalobill Don't use an animator and call directly GLAutoDrawable.display(), this is an analogue of glutPostRedisplay but in my humble opinion, it's not the best solution. The least tricky solution consists in calling OpenGL only in GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable), getting the values of properly synchronized variables in this method and setting them in the method(s) of the key listener. Trying to mimic GLUT (I used it to write my very first blueprint of first person shooter in C++) in Java leads to badly designed code.

Comment: @gouessey: I think you don't fully understand me. 1) I think that `GLAutoDrawable.display()` invokes the rendering code immediately rather than posting a repaint request to the system. That would be wrong here. 2) I'm not proposing to render from inside a key listener. I'm proposing to invalidate the window. This is a matter of how underling windowing systems work, java or not. E.g. on Windows I would `Invalidate()` and render in `WM_PAINT`, using OpenGL as a substitute to GDI. If you are not doing a real-time animation, then redrawing your UI at max framerate *is* a bad design.